# Cosa vuol dire "di buon giusto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Quell’antica ragazza* di Beppe Fenoglio ho letto:

> Disse Matteo: – È stato un buono sfogo per i nostri maschi.
>         – Ma ora hanno preso il vizio, – osservò la mezzadra, – e chi glielo mantiene?
>         – Cominciare dovevano pur cominciare, – rispose Matteo, e a sua figlia Domenica che si muoveva tutta nervosa disse: – Tu tieni il sangue fermo, ché presto ti maritiamo ed avrai anche tu quel che ti spetta. Ma **di buon giusto**.

Sapreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "di buon giusto" che appare in questo passaggio? L'ho cercata alla voce "giusto" di parecchi dizionari (inclusi il Treccani e il GDLI), ma non l'ho trovata.

Curiosamente, però, facendo uso della funzione "ricerca in sequenza" del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ho trovato un'altra [citazione di Fenoglio](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000392.jpg) in cui si può leggere questa stessa espressione  (appare come esempio di uso di "strofinare" per "passare  più  volte  il  pollice  contro  l’indice  per  al­ludere al denaro"):

> «Com’è  che  il  cugi­no  Osvaldo  non  è  al  fronte?»  «Credo  l’abbiano  riformato».  «**Di 
>   buon giusto** o per questi?» dissi strofinando pollice ed indice.

Comment: A proposito della citazione nel Grande dizionario… È il gesto di strofinare pollice e indice (e anche medio) che indica i soldi. Quindi, nella seconda citazione che proponi, la domanda significherebbe: «L’hanno riformato a ragione / perché c’era una motivazione valida o perché ha pagato / corrotto qualcuno?».

Comment: Penso che il senso di “buon giusto” sia “giustamente”. Non ho mai sentito usare quest’espressione e non la trovo citata da nessuna parte. Forse un regionalismo o una forma arcaica, o un gioco di parole sulla più comune espressione “di buon gusto.”.

Comment: Suona un po' come “a buon diritto”.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG che assomiglia a "a buon diritto". A mio avviso l'espressione costituisce una specie di rafforzativo. Non solo quel di cui si parla è "giusto" (o "giustamente") ma è "particolarmente" giusto. Assomiglia anche all'espressione ecclesiastica "è cosa buona e giusta".

Comment: @Gio: In effetti, facendo ricerca su Google Libri, questa espressione si trova su qualche commedia di Goldoni e alcuni libri ottocenteschi editati a Torino.